# Multiple subplots in one pdf page figure with matplotlib

Tags: python-2.7, pdf, matplotlib, subplot

I know the question was asked already , but I've tried to change my code with different solutions found here and there without success.

I want to make a report of multiple pdf pages , with multiple plots on each page, here is a piece of code for the first page, it is not complete but the remainder is written the same way with differrent plotting.
I tried first using subplot2grid method, then basic figure and subplot method. I could see that the subplots were plotted but it seemed that the final pdf contained only the last subplot, so I guess the problem comes from the subplots saving ?

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
with PdfPages('Rapport_criblage.pdf') as pdf_pages:

plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)

plt.subplot(421)  

moyenne_ratio=[]
moyenne_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlpos[0])
moyenne_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlneg[0])

SD_ratio=[]
SD_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlpos[1])
SD_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlneg[1])

pos = numpy.arange(2)
width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram
ax1 = plt.axes()
ax1.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax1.set_xticklabels("+-")
plt.bar(pos, moyenne_ratio, width, color='b',yerr=SD_ratio) 

txt_r=" RATIO \n cellules+tampon: \n moyenne          ecart-type          CV \n"+ \
    str(etu_ratio_ctrlneg)+"\n"+ \
    "cellules+OT: \n moyenne          ecart-type          CV \n"+ \
    str(etu_ratio_ctrlpos)+"\n"+ \
    "Z: "+str(Zpos_vs_neg_ratio)

ax1.text(0.1,0.1,txt_r,horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='center',transform = ax1.transAxes)   

plt.subplot(422)
ratio_max_basal=[]
puits=[]
for l in ctrlneg:
    ratio_max_basal.append(l[5])
    puits.append(l[7])

pos = numpy.arange(len(ratio_max_basal))
width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram
ax2 = plt.axes()
ax2.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
ax2.set_xticklabels(puits)
plt.bar(pos, ratio_max_basal, width, color='b') 

pdf_pages.savefig()
```

Here is my last try with the "fig.add_subplot()" method, but I get weird blank figures

```
 from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
 with PdfPages('Rapport_criblage.pdf') as pdf_pages:
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)

    axis1=fig.add_subplot(421)  

    moyenne_ratio=[]
    moyenne_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlpos[0])
    moyenne_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlneg[0])
    SD_ratio=[]
    SD_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlpos[1])
    SD_ratio.append(etu_ratio_ctrlneg[1])

    pos = numpy.arange(2)
    width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram
    ax1 = plt.axes()
    ax1.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
    ax1.set_xticklabels("+-")
    axis1.bar(pos, moyenne_ratio, width, color='b',yerr=SD_ratio) 

    txt_r=" RATIO \n cellules+tampon: \n moyenne          ecart-type          CV \n"+ \
    str(etu_ratio_ctrlneg)+"\n"+ \
    "cellules+OT: \n moyenne          ecart-type          CV \n"+ \
    str(etu_ratio_ctrlpos)+"\n"+ \
    "Z: "+str(Zpos_vs_neg_ratio)

     axis1.text(0.1,0.1,txt_r,horizontalalignment='left',verticalalignment='center',transform = ax1.transAxes)   

    axis2=fig.add_subplot(422)
    ratio_max_basal=[]
    puits=[]
    for l in ctrlneg:
        ratio_max_basal.append(l[5])
        puits.append(l[7])

    pos = numpy.arange(len(ratio_max_basal))
    width = 1.0     # gives histogram aspect to the bar diagram
    ax2 = plt.axes()
    ax2.set_xticks(pos + (width / 2))
    ax2.set_xticklabels(puits)
    axis2.bar(pos, ratio_max_basal, width, color='b') 


    pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
```

I begin with matplotlib and maybe it's obvious but I don't get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works to create a 2 page pdf, with 2 subplots on page 1 and 3 subplots on page 2. Maybe you need to call `pdf_pages.close()` after writing all your figures in your second example?

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)

pp.savefig(fig)

fig2=plt.figure()
ax1=fig2.add_subplot(311)
ax2=fig2.add_subplot(312)
ax3=fig2.add_subplot(313)

pp.savefig(fig2)

pp.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I tried it but it seems that only the last subplot (the one just before the savefig and close) appears on the pdf, taking up all the room

Comment: Ok, I filled the code you gave me with a piece of mine, corresponding to the first subplot, and it returned  a cthulhean picture... no just the subplot hidding behind its neighbours, so I guess it is a matter of figure size, stupid ! I 'll have to check how to squeeze my figs with the proper dimension then.

Comment: Actually, can we control subplot size ? I think it is suposed to be done automatically no ? I added some axes after 1 and 2 , I filled 1 and 2  with plot data. I think the ax1 and ax2 are superposed (I see only ax2 taking all the room at the background with the empty remaining subplots over it). I don't understand why this is happening...

Comment: If I put my data before all the plotting and gridspec related lines it works, I guess this is the reason then.